# Not getting back related lists from a query

Tags: rest-api, query, related-list, master-detail

Is there any way to get Salesforce to return related lists when I lookup an object using their API?

Right now I am searching Contact objects for an email address and I am able to get back all the single fields (both standard fields and fields we've added) but I don't get any of the related lists (either standard or custom).

I initially was going to Contact, getting the ID and then I would try and do another query on the related list object, but I think because this is a master-detail relationship you can't search on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a inner query to achive this.

[Salesforce SOQL Subquery and Custom Objects with Apex](http://raydehler.com/cloud/clod/salesforce-soql-subquery-and-custom-objects-with-apex.html)

The sample example will be like,

```
List<Account> accountList = [Select Id, Name,(Select id from AccountContactRoles), (Select Id from Contacts)   from Account where Id=: 'some id'];

System.debug('###'+accountList);

for(Account obj : accountList){
    System.debug(':::'+obj.Contacts);
    System.debug(':::'+obj.AccountContactRoles);
}
```

You can verify the Relationship name using Workbench --> Info --> Standard and Custom Object -> Select and Object for which Relationship to be verified

[image]